# Do all (finite) group ring projections come from subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, c-star-algebras

I am struggling to find a reference for what I imagine is considered a simple result (or is it false?!).

Let $G$ be a **finite** group, $\mathbb{C}G$ its group ring. For any subgroup $H\subseteq G$, the element
$$p_H=\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{h\in H}\delta^h$$
is an idempotent in the group ring such that $p_H(g)=\overline{p_H(g^{-1})}$ (this is an edit of the question). So that it is actually a projection in the $*$-algebra $\mathbb{C}G$.

> Are all the projections in $\mathbb{C}G$ of the form $p_H$, or are
>   there projections that don't come from a subgroup?

**EDIT:** The answer is already no for $G=C_3$ where we have the following four projections (thanks to rschwieb). They are 
$$\{p_{\{e\}},p_{C_3}, p_{\{e\}}-p_{C_3},0\}.$$

Perhaps the projections live in the linear span of $\{p_H:H\subset G\}$ but this goes beyond what I was looking for. The answer to the question is no.

Comment: @Shaun thanks for the edit. The first time any of my questions have been edited for the better.

Comment: I'm not efficient at extracting a complete set of idempotents from even a toy example like $\mathbb C[C_3]$... but is there any obvious reason why an example can't be found for something like $G=C_p$ for a prime?

Comment: Is $\delta^h$ defined so that $\delta(h) = 1 \in G$ and $\delta(g) = 0$ for all $g \neq h$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes.

Comment: @rschwieb this is probably something that is well known either way and not necessarily something to be attacked from scratch.

Comment: @MatthewTowers trying now. Candidates look like $a\delta^0+b\delta^1+b\delta^2$.

Comment: For abelian $G$, the group algebra is $\ast$-isomorphic to the complex-valued functions on $G$ via Fourier transform. In the latter, it is easy to find all projections (they are just characteristic functions of subsets).

Comment: Could somebody tell me what I'm missing?
$$
\left[\sum_{g \in G} \alpha_g\delta^g\right]^2 = 
\sum_{g \in G} \sum_{h \in G} \alpha_g \alpha_h \delta^g\delta^h = 
\sum_{h \in G} \alpha_1 \alpha_h \delta^1 \delta^h = 
\alpha_1 \sum_{h \in G} \alpha_h \delta^h
$$
which seems to imply that a linear combination of $\delta^h$'s is idempotent if and only if $\alpha_1 = 1$, which doesn't line up with the discussion so far.  Should it be that $\delta^h(h) = h$ instead of $\delta^h(h) = 1$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the multiplication is $\delta^g\delta^h=\delta^{gh}$. This is where you are getting eight idempotents from 0-1 diagonal matrices.

Comment: Presumably $1-p_H$ is almost never of the form $p_{H'}$ for any subgroup $H'$

Comment: Never because $e$ is in every subgroup.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy I guess I'm _still_ a little bit foggy on what exactly your condition is. You just want the idempotent to be invariant under the mapping $g\mapsto g^{-1}$? Then clearly $1-p_H$ is like that, and it isn't of the form $p_{H'}$.   Or are you counting that as arising from a group?

Comment: I now think $(2/3,-1/3,-1/3)$ is another... that is $\delta^e-p_{C_3}$. Will get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: I changed the title to be "projections" instead of "idempotents" so that readers won't be fooled by it the way I was...

Comment: @rschwieb thank you good change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $C_3$ is the cyclic group of order $3$, then $\mathbb C[C_3]\cong\mathbb C^3$, which has $8$ idempotents.

If you impose the condition that the idempotent is invariant after $g\mapsto g^{-1}$, then there are four idempotents that do that: the trivial ones, plus $e=1/3(1+c+c^2)$ and $1-e$.

The latter one is definitely not of the form $p_H$.

Comment: I think that he's asking for idempotents that also satisfy $p(g^{-1}) = p(g)$

Comment: I've re-opened as a community wiki because I gather the example I suggested might actually be useful, although I myself don't actually know the details..

Comment: @JPMcCarthy What do you mean there are not that many idempotents?  You mean there aren't that many *projections*?  $\mathbb C^3$ clearly has $8$ idempotents...

Comment: Anyhow, it does turn out that there are four idempotents invariant under that mapping $g\mapsto g^{-1}$

Comment: I took my time and four four two. My four are $0,p_{\{e\}}$, $p_{C_3}$ and $p_{\{e\}}-p_{C_3}=1_{\mathbf{C}C_3}-p_{C_3}$. What is $c$?